# provide 3.7v source to android tablet

Tags: batteries, transformer, ac, android

Android tablet mostly needed a 3.7V Lion battery to run on it. If I were to replace the battery with a power source, how can I provide such a 3.7V source from some existing products such as 220V/5V or 220V/12V charger/ transformers. Any costly effective to do this?
Thanks

Comment: That sounds silly. Either replace the battery or plug the tablet in.

Comment: Why would you want to, when you can just plug 5V into the charger USB port?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the OP didn't say the battery is dead, he just want to use power supply instead. and no they won't work with the plug if there is no battery, circuits in these tablets and phones are designed to work only when there is a battery.

Comment: @Majenko: Because some of them when running on full cpu/gpu consume more battery than what the charger can deliver.

Comment: `circuits in these tablets and phones are designed to work only when there is a battery.` *citation needed*

Comment: It's called a voltage regulator. Use a Switching power regulator (Buck regulator) to bring down the voltage efficiently. Keep in mind some devices will not work off "battery" if the battery has active circuity to monitor temperature or charge.

Comment: @Passerby: how do I start with to make a voltage regulator. Just two resistors to divide over two voltages? Will that consume too much power? also, are there other ways too? Can I make use of existing 220v/5v charger?

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: don't want to buy another battery as it will dies too in future. Put the tablet on the desk at home to use as, say a digital big clock.

Comment: @Passerby: in my case, the cheap Tablet has only 2 leads, so it may not have any temperature control. so in other cases, it may have 3 leads?

Comment: Usually there is a thermistor in the battery pack to allow temperature sensing. Smaller battery packs may omit it. Sometimes there will be 4 or more leads on a battery pack. For example, it could provide both sides of the thermistor, instead of connecting it to ground inside the pack, or there could be multiple wires to reduce wire resistance.

Comment: In my case, the cheap Tablet has only 2 leads and also the inside battery, so it may not have any temperature control. Will a variable potentiometer that adjust to 3.7v output will provide some simple test that I can test if the tablet can run or not?

Comment: If I plan to work with a voltage regulator to provide 3.7v, how the circuit should be drawn? do I need to calculate ampere current output?

Comment: There is some useful links about potentiometer to provide a 3.7V in this forum. Look for it and some days I will find them useful when I want to do this. Thank for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 220AC/5VDC power source, then you can use a linear regulator to get the 3.7VDC.  The LM317 is adjustable and probably has plenty of capacity, but be sure to check the specs.